# Android (Java) | Firestore security rules: allow access only to paths contains user's email

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have to set up the Firestore rules that this code should insert data only if the directory in "users" collection is equaled to the user's email:

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
String email = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection("users").document(email).set("Important data");
```

Now I have the following rules that allow any readings and writings everywhere (if user is authed):

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see my Firestore has the following structure:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- users (collections)
    |     |
    |     --- email: mymail@google.com(document)
    |            | 
    |            --- Data
    |     --- email: othermail@google.com(document)
    |            | 
    |            --- Data2
    ...
    --- messages (collections)
    |     |
    |     --- email: mymail@google.com(document)
    |            | 
    |            --- message
    |     --- email: othermail@google.com(document)
    |            | 
    |            --- message2
```

How can we deny access if user "mymail@google.com" is trying to read "othermail@google.com"'s data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's **much cleaner** if the documents are identified by the user's UID rather than their email.  If you can make change, everything gets easier, and you have fewer problems in the future.  You can simply use `request.auth.uid` to compare to each document ID.

If you really can't use the UID and must use the email (which is not great), you can use [request.auth.token.email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth) (note that the linked doc suggests that an email address might not be present for a user, in which case, you're out of luck for that user).

You have to call out each document by its name:

```
    match /messages/{id} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.email == id;
    }
    match /users/{id} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.email == id;
    }
```

Comment: I have to complement: I auth users via Google. They have a unique email anyway. Is it not a good reason to still using user's emails?

Comment: Imagine if you wanted to allow a different auth provider in the future that doesn't provide email.  Also, email addresses are not case-sensitive.  What do you do if someone enters something that doesn't match exactly, but is still a valid email?  UID is the universal solution, and is seen throughout the security rules documentation.  But it's up to you.